# Unable to load a templateURL for the stateprovider otherwise option

Tags: angularjs

I'm unable to load the template url for otherwise state but,able to redirect to specified url.I had tried using urlRouterProvider but of no use.

Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

My js:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


            $stateProvider  
               .state('home', {
                        url: 'abc/home',
                        templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
                    })

               .state('about',{
                        url:'abc/about',
                        controller:'KPIAnalyzeCtrl',
                        templateUrl:'views/about.html'
                    })
               .state('otherwise', {
                        url: 'abc/home',
                        templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
                    });


//  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('abc/home');


   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Otherwise does not work with any templates, it's not a state. It's a "redirect" url. So if you type non-existing url, it will "redirect" to that one, so it should be a valid state (or a server response if you don't want it to be within SPA)

So e.g. if you do abc/blahblah, then it will go to abc/home. In your example it seems that you need to remove the otherwise state and then it should work redirecting you to the home state.

```
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


        $stateProvider  
           .state('home', {
                    url: 'abc/home',
                    templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
                })

           .state('about',{
                    url:'abc/about',
                    controller:'KPIAnalyzeCtrl',
                    templateUrl:'views/about.html'
                });


       $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('abc/home');
```

});

Comment: Actually on load of a page I should load home state.I've used the above code but unable to load the templateUrl

Comment: I did not quite get what you mean, but if you type in the browser http://yourhost/abc/home and it will work properly, then http://yourhost/blahblha should redirect you to /abc/home as if you typed it.

Comment: Actually in the home page,I have a template which is not loading for on page load

Comment: That is totally different problem then, not connected to the otherwise. You need to verify that the url exists and returns the data, I see that you don't sepcify controller for it, so it might be the problem. You can also check your console in the browser for more information on what's going on.

Comment: If you liked the answer please vote and accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. You need to point to the state in urlRouterProvider

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


        $stateProvider  
           .state('home', {
                    url: 'abc/home',
                    templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
                })

           .state('about',{
                    url:'abc/about',
                    controller:'KPIAnalyzeCtrl',
                    templateUrl:'views/about.html'
                })
           .state('otherwise', {
                    url: '/otherwise',
                    templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
                });

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/otherwise');
```

});

Answer (score 0):

As you want to load home state on Page load, use the below code or change the home state from below code.

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider  
       .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
            })

       .state('about',{
                url:'abc/about',
                controller:'KPIAnalyzeCtrl',
                templateUrl:'views/about.html'
            })
       .state('otherwise', {
                url: '/otherwise',
                templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
            });

          $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
 })
```